# Issue with eclipse DDMS while creating emulator of 4.0

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Recently i added android 4.0 into the SDK Manager and installed it.But after this while i am creating a emulator of 4.0,in DDMS after sometime the emulator is getting disappear.Anyone any idea plz help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should reinstall SDK 4.0, it may be corrected during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug. You can fix it by restarting adb. Execute

```
adb kill-server
```

followed by

```
adb start-server
```

from the command line. The emulator should reappear. The `adb` command can be found in the `ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools` directory.

Comment: I closed the Eclipse and end the adb from taskmanager and restrat eclipse.But the same problem. :(

Comment: If you killed adb from the task manager, it's probably not running now (which will show no device either). Try the way i explained here on the command line. If you are not sure how to do this tell me, ill add a short guide in this case.

Comment: @alextsc.Thanks buddy.But adb is running properly as a process in my task manager.anyway let me try your method.And also i recreated a new emulator, and tested many times but no work.

Comment: Ok. That fixed it for me when i encountered that bug. Don't know any other solutions. Maybe someone else knows more.